# How to host flutter application in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm following the [instructions](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-host-your-flutter-web-app-with-firebase-hosting-67d3e4657002) I've installed CLI on Windows, but the command `firebase init hosting` is failing when I'm running it in VS Code Terminal:

```
PS D:\flutter\first_app> npm install -g firebase-tools                                                          
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be 
problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 701 packages, and audited 702 packages in 29s

46 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS D:\flutter\first_app> firebase init hosting
firebase : File C:\Users\Nafanya\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase init hosting
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS D:\flutter\first_app>
```

I don't know what is the problem. Any suggestions here?